# What options are there for getting help with job hunting? Especially abroad

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom, europe, netherlands

2 months ago I decided that I didn't like the life I have in the town I moved to a year ago for my current job. So, I dusted off my CV and submitted it to every site I could think of, expecting to get a phone call in the next fortnight.

I got over 40 emails in the first week and my phone went off in meetings at work 3 times a day. I had to stick a call forward to my voice mail for all numbers just to curb the disturbances. This goes against all my expectations for job hunting.

I am far too tired in the evenings to spend more than an hour or 2 every other night just replying to everyone. Replying to everyone means I don't have time to actually look and apply for jobs I want; I worry that I'm forgetting or missing followups between all spam I'm getting; and I feel so pressured that I don't have time to think whether I actually qualify for, or whether I even want any of the jobs recruiters are telling me about. I don't feel that I have time to put any real time to focus on any one application, and now the emails and phone calls are slowing down, telling me people are starting to not bother with me because I'm too slow to react.

I feel like I need to quit my current job to have time to deal with it all, but that's going to make me less attractive. I need a second pair of hands to help me. Who is out there that can help me, and what are the options for someone in my position?

P.S. I'm a firmware engineer in the UK looking to go to Europe, probably the Netherlands. Learning dutch while I job hunt was the plan, but the job hunting leaves me no time or energy.

Comment: Does that cost? How much does that cost? Where does one find such an agency? Am I wrong for assuming all the head-hunters that contact me won't take work "the other way round"?

Comment: I'm looking for someone who'll work for me, who will help me manage all the agencies that are being paid by the hiring companies that keep contacting me (as well as someone who can help me find, apply for and manage applications to hiring companies that are not using head-hunters).

Comment: Expect much higher tax rates in Holland. Also, there is not much point in learning Dutch as everyone there speaks fluent English (at least I failed to find anyone who did not when I worked there. I don't just mean in the office. The bus driver had a larger English vocabulary than me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have presented your situation in a somewhat contradictory way. You say you want to change jobs/countries but you also say that in the evenings you have no time/focus to reply to follow up emails about potential jobs.

If a company has gone as far as contacting you back on an application you should at least respond to them in a timely manner.

> Who is out there that can help me, and what are the options for someone in my position?

Contact a recruiter, they can be annoying but they will do this work for you.

If it's a recruiter who is pushing for you to interview for a role then make extra sure they're not just trying to shoehorn you into any role they can. Recruiter's just want to make commission they don't care about you. It's better if you can do this yourself

Comment: I'm not sure how it is contradictory to say there's something I want to do but I'm struggling to find time to do it. I actually have yet to apply for any roles; all my time so far had been spent replying to voice mails and emails from recruiters. I want aware that the recruiters that keep contacting me worked "the other way", I thought head hunters would only looked for people and I would need a different specialist to help me find a company.

Comment: if you really want a new job you will find time to do it, if I hate a job it gives me motivation and energy to find a new one. I can understand being tired in the evenings but you surely have time on the weekends?

Answer (score 1):

You need was is commonly called a Headhunter, you can look around for agencies that provide such service.

They usually go about handling a lot of the organisational stuff for you.

You get in Contact describe what exactly you are looking for and in a few days they usually come back with some positions and you can decide which ones you want to follow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Google Voice (it's free and now available in the UK).

   a) It's easier to forward calls on a schedule that way.

   b) They transcribe all the calls in real time and send them to your email.

   c) Google Voice also makes it easier to work with an assistant.
2. Use a separate gmail address as well.
3. I suppose you could hire an intern to be your assistant.
4. Do not go through 3rd party recruiters that were not recommended to you. Or if you must go through a 3rd party recruiter, only go through 3rd party recruiters that have an exclusive relationship with their client. In other words, only respond to ads that contain the name of the company that's hiring.